# Pass an array back from a JNI function to without copying it

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to use JNI to process large chunks of data using C++ however I am having trouble understanding weather the function SetArrayRegion will duplicate an array element by element or if it can just leave the data in place and return it to the calling java function.

The following documentation is where I have been reading about it but it is still unclear what is going on.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You should ask yourself, why are you worried about this and what you are trying to achieve.  If you are doing this for performance reasons, you could try direct buffers, but depending on how it is used it can be slower than doing a copy. i.e. making a JNI call for each peice of data can be mroe expensive.

Comment: The data I am passing is frequently big enough that a few extra copies laying around can fill up the system ram so just from that perspective it is worth it.  Also I would think it would need to be a extremely slow call for it to be quicker to copy data when it gets to be in the hundreds of megabytes range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally when you pass data via JNI it will be copied across the JNI boundary.  If you want an efficient mechanism for passing data from native space up to Java space then you should look at how to access NIO direct byte buffers.  This can provide a section of memory that can be shared between native code and Java code.  Look at [`GetDirectBufferAddress`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#GetDirectBufferAddress).

Comment: Thank you, I believe that is the function I was looking for.

Comment: I am still wondering what is the most efficient method to transfer huge arrays (say double[100000])) across jni boundaries. The "GetDirectBufferAddress" may only be useful in the case of raw byte arrays. Can someone more qualified comment on it.