# How to pass an array from C to Java over JNI without making a copy

Tags: java, android, c

in `C` I have

```
int left = ..., top = ..., width = ..., height = ...;
void *pixels = GetScreenshot(left, top, width, height);

// use JNI to call SaveImageToGallery

::free(pixels);
```

in Java I have

```
public void SaveImageToGallery(int[] pixels, int width, int height)
{
    // ...
}
```

How do I pass `pixels` to Java function `SaveImageToGallery` using JNI without making a copy of them?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944717/pass-an-array-back-from-a-jni-function-to-without-copying-it (I didn't vote it as one, though, because I have the ability to close Java posts with one flag, and I'm not sure enough to do that here.)

Comment: We can't do that, but if you have the possibility of changing the signature of `SaveImageToGallery()` to accept a direct NIO buffer instead of a Java array, then it would be possible with `NewDirectBuffer()`.